# Free paypal cart solution

Tags: plugins, customization, plugin-recommendation, paypal

Does someone some good & free paypal cart solution for wordpress?

I was looking at phpurchase.com, that looks good but I don't want to buy it since it's for a test project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the [simple paypal shopping cart plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-simple-paypal-shopping-cart/)? It looks like it is just waht you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple:

http://getshopped.org/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/eshop/

Answer (score 0):

woo cart & cart 66

I think cart 66 is simple enough for a paypal, make sure to set the checkout page to proper shortcode.  Woo cart does a lot more but may be too complex

Both are freemium - the paypal only will be 100% free